# yahoo only indexes my home page

Tags: seo, sitemap, yahoo

It seems though Yahoo only indexes one of my urls (my home page) from my XML sitemap.
I've tried resubmitting - no luck. And I noticed that Yahoo hasn't crawled my site in awhile either (I've changed my title since as noted in the picture).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yahoo is now powered by Bing](http://www.websitepublisher.net/blog/2010/08/17/bing-to-power-yahoo-next-week/). You should [submit your sitemap there](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster).

Comment: Oh, I've already got it submitted there ;) Never knew that happend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to submit .TXT file sitemap so that yahoo crawler will able to index the all pages.